# Clang-Tidy Narrowing Conversion from uint8_t to float

Tags: c++, clang-tidy, cpp-core-guidelines

I'm getting a clang-tidy warning that reads `narrowing conversion from 'int' to 'float'` when I convert from a `uint8_t` to a `float`, which to my understanding is not a narrowing conversion since `float` can represent every integer that a `uint8_t` can.

Code example:

```
uint8_t testVar = 8;
float test2 = 2.0f * testVar;
```

clang-tidy flags the second line of that with the warning `cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions: narrowing conversion from 'int' to 'float'`. In my IDE, the squiggle shows up under the `testVar`.

According to the [reference](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions.html), this warning should be flagged if we convert from `an integer to a narrower floating-point (e.g. uint64_t to float)`, but to the best of my knowledge, `float` is not narrower than `uint8_t`.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding these data types, or is something else going on here?

I'm on LLVM version 11.0.0 if that matters.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `uint8_t` is implicitly converted to `unsigned` before it is then converted to `float`. Obviously clang-tidy is not being very smart.

Comment: @john Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the `u` already stood for `unsigned`. My IDE tells me that `uint8_t` is just an alias for `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yes but the rules of C++ say that when you use a `uint8_t` in an expression it is implicitly converted to `unsigned int`. This is called [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions)

Comment: Clearly clang-tidy is not going deep enough. Here are two points which might be misleading it. 1. `float` is signed which is always smaller than the range of `unsigned` types. 2. `float` covers smaller range than `int`. Although uint8_t ultimately boils down to something equivalent of `unsigned char` but as stated before, clang-tidy is not going that deep.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is this warning generated when you actually *run* clang-tidy, or is it just a squiggle in your IDE's text editor? If the latter, then it may be that the "IntelliSense" feature of your IDE isn't properly using clang-tidy. Using the clang static analyser in VS-2019, I don't get that warning.